# How does pad_packed_sequence work in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Output of LSTM in pytorch:  [image]
I gave the input as packed sequence (birectional LSTM) then acording to the doucments only
`output` is packed and `h_n`, `c_n` are returned as tensor? After applying `pad_packed_sequence` function to `output` to unpack it how do I get hidden states as tensor? I saw somewhere this code: `pad_packed_sequence(output)[0]`, why do we have to take 0-index here? Also for last hidden and cell state I get tensors using `h_n[0],h_n[1]` and `c_n[0],c_n[1]`. In this case 0 and 1 indexing is done to get forward and backward hidden and cell states. I don't understand the 0-indexing for `output` and why is h_[n] and c_[n] not returned as paked sequence also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should take 0-index, because **pad_packed_sequence** returns output and the output_lengths.